# Retrieve serial number backup w/o booting from external

Tags: external-hard-drive, windows-registry, windows-backup

I have a back up copy of my Windows XP operating system in an external hard drive ever since I upgraded to Windows 7. I cannot find the XP serial number to install on another computer. I can access the files, but I cannot boot XP off the external hard drive to install a password sniffer to get the XP serial number, but I keep getting the BSOD.

How can I get the XP serial number?

Answer (score 1):

[Install ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html)

When Produkey loads press F9 to open the Select Source window. Click on the second option down “Load the product keys of external Windows installations from all disks currently plugged to your computer” and then click OK.

[image]

.
Windows and Office keys will then be displayed for you to write down or save to a text file.
[image]